# Robust RGB encoding of floats using JPEG?

Tags: algorithm, glsl, shader

I am trying to encode data, floating point values (0-1), in the RGB channels of a texture, to be used as input in a GLSL shader. Each pixel represents one float.

For reasons that is not important for this discussion, it is an hard requirement to use standard jpeg, which is a lossy format, to carry this texture, and the compression ratio used can be anything as it is in the control of the content creators. They want to keep compression as high as possible as the amount of data is massive and will consume expensive bandwidth (we are talking high volume of transactions of large datasets), while expecting minimal negative impact on the final result from the shader.

There are several ways to encode floats in RGB channels, however, I am looking for a method that is as robust as possible and degrades as little as possible when using higher jpeg compression ratios, inducing those jpeg artifacts.

The straight forward and most common method, that works well with a lossless format like PNG, is to simply take each channel and scale it up. Something like

```
//Given RGB=0-255
decodedNormalized=(float)0xffffff / (R<<16|G<<8|B)
```

But in this example scary things happens when blue degrades for example, as it could lead to massive amounts of noise. While noise in the blue channel is not a big deal.

Of course, noise is unavoidable, but how to minimize it and have it degrade more gracefully?

I am thinking using HSB rather than RGB might be better, as I know the JPEG algorithm devotes more bits to brightness than the color itself, due to our eyes being more sensitive to brightness changes than color changes. So, the brightness component might have less noise than the HS components. This I can probably use to my advantage. For example by letting B represent the most significant digit.

Another idea is to simply scale down each RGB component and ignore the floating point part. Which means 24 bits lossy data, becomes for example 18 bits more stable data (8x8x8 -> 6x6x6), or perhaps use an uneven bit configuration like 8x8x8->5x6x7. That still gives decent precision.

This is just something of the top of my head though. There might be good shader (my target is GLSL) algorithms out there already than can handle this better?

Comment: Are the requirements fixed? 1 float for each pixel or on average? Do you want to get the exact float (float32?) or reasonably accurate?

Comment: Here you can read about typical bits per pixel for different JPEG compression settings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Sample_photographs If this is not enough, you either have to create a larger texture or compress your floats. There are several difficulties to restore even the mentioned bits: You have to get an exact pixel of the texture, not averaged or filtered or interpolated. You have to guess, which information is kept. If you are nearly there and are restoring several floats at the same time, you can apply an error correction code to get the last few missing bits.

Comment: Thanks for your input Sebastian. 32 bits precision is impossible as jpeg only has 8 bits per color channel. So, 24 bits would be the absolute max precision, given lossless compression. The quality of the output from our shader will gradually degrade as the floating point accuracy decreases. It is hard to say exactly how many bits of accuracy would be enough, the output is visual, and the lower the accuracy the higher chance of visible artifacts. There are a lot of factors to consider in the whole scenario here, and as the input is user generated we cannot hard code any assumption.

Comment: @sinsro: "*I am thinking using HSB rather than RGB might be better*" JPEG (or more specifically, JFIF compression) starts by converting to YCbCr format. So double-conversion won't really be effective here.

Comment: Is it possible to make the JPEG texture larger? Can you access more than one pixel (at least the neighboring ones)? Even if not, a larger JPEG texture could be filtered by the 3D pipeline. And even if this also does not happen, you can avoid JPEG artifacts. Are to be encoded floating point values near together similar? The general difficulty with JPEG is that it is filtered blockwise and that it reduces higher frequencies. If you want to keep them, you will run into difficulties. If you increase the texture size, each of your target coordinates just gets one JPEG block.

Comment: You can estimate the size of texture needed: Write your data to an array, increase the image size by a factor of n (e.g. x16 in x and y dimension), compress it to JPEG (e.g. with default settings of a graphics program), reload it, decrease the size by nearest pixel or bilinear or bicubic interpolation and look at the resulting data and the size of the intermediate JPEG data (file size). Calculate the number of bits per pixel of the JPEG.

Comment: If the JPEG is compressed like 5 bits per pixel and the floating point data is not continuous, you cannot expect each RGB/HSB channel to carry more than 1 to 2 bits! Compare this to 32 bits for float32. Even combining the channel bits, a float32 has 8 bit exponent and 1 bit sign and 23 bits for the fraction. To be able to have the same array of possible values, you would assign 1 bit to sign and 4 bits to exponent and assume the mantissa to be just a `1`. The exponent would be left-shifted by 4 bits. Your possible values would be apart: +/- ..., 1/4096, 1/256, 1/16, 1, 16, 256, 4096, ...

Comment: Having a larger texture and some (3D pipeline) filtering would help, as more texture pixels would be averaged, so you would get a finer resolution of the resulting float. Without algorithm (so no manual reading of neighboring pixels), just averaging, you would need 4 times the number of pixels (double the width and height) to get one bit more output. The OpenGL pipeline would not average to many neighboring pixels (perhaps two to 32, giving 0.5 to 2.5 more bits). Perhaps you have a moving scene and can average over time somehow? Probably not. Can you reduce the value interval from +/-10^+-38?

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is good for colors because that's what it was *designed* to compress. It is designed to compress colors in a way that the decompression artifacts are not particularly noticeable to human beings. It was not designed to compress arbitrary binary data that is intended to be interpreted as an IEEE-754 32-bit floating point value. And pretty much anything you try to do is going to run into that as a fundamental problem.

You have designed yourself into a corner, such that the parameters of the problem make solving it functionally impossible. JPEG is not going to work for what you need, and the result is always going to be substantially broken. That is the nature of the parameters of your problem.

Comment: I specifically pointed out that jpeg is a hard requirement and this decision is not to be discussed here. If you knew the whole complex image you would understand why this requirement makes perfect sense, we have considered all the obvious points you raise here long time ago and a whole lot more. Please stay on topic, complaining about the hard requirement is not helpful. Thanks

Comment: However hard that requirement is, the thing you are being asked to do just cannot happen. It's like, if you have an object weighting 15,000 pounds, and someone tells you to lift it with a wench that can pull 10,000 pounds, no amount of saying "it's a hard requirement" will change the fact that said "hard requirement" makes the task impossible.

Comment: It is impossible for you for sure. No need to comment on things you do not know anything about, and attacking the requirements is not helpful at all. My team is getting close to a good solution already, just finalizing testing and benchmarking now, so the only thing you prove here is you would never get a job in our company.